# Can Python avoid reevaluation in a statement?

Tags: python

I have the following statement in Python, where ori is a string

```
[ori[ori.rfind(' ') + 1:], ori[:ori.rfind(' ')]]
```

We can see ori.rfind(' ') is called twice, is the interpreter smart enough to just evaluate the function only once?

We could do the following:

```
    s = ori.rfind(' ')
    return [ori[s+1:], ori[:s]]
```

But this uses two lines. I intend to use this statement in a list comprehension over list of strings and hope this function is one line.

In this case, it is actually easier for the interpreter to figure out, since string is an immutable. My guess is perhaps interpreter can be smart to avoid reevaluation. In general, if the object is an immutable, could the interpreter be smart enough?

Comment: "uses two lines so less pythonic"?!

Comment: why would it be less pythonic?

Comment: Using two lines is *incorrect* in almost all cases. And when it's correct, it rarely matters. And when it's correct and matters, it's usually too friggin hard to do automatically.

Comment: @DSM Evaluating only one call when there should be two according to the language rules is usually incorrect (because the call may have side effects). Using two lines is, of course, perfectly fine.

Comment: @NPE I should not have said using two lines is less pythonic. The primary reason is I want to use it in the list comprehension, which is preferred in Python. I wanted to do [[ori[ori.rfind(' ') + 1:], ori[:ori.rfind(' ')]] for ori in some_list_of_string]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way the interpreter could safely execute the sub-expression `ori.rfind(' ')` once is if it knew that

1. The rFind expression didn't perform any mutations
2. No expression between the first and second use of `rFind` caused any mutations

If any of this wasn't true then caching the result and reusing would be simply unsafe.  Given the dynamic nature of Python it's nearly impossible to have these guarantees hence operations like this couldn't be cached + reused

Comment: +1, This is a really good explanation of why the suggested optimization just doesn't work.

Comment: @Lattyware To be fair, the real problem is that methods can be redefined around any corner. All the other problems mentioned are shared by say Java, but the Hotspot JIT would have no problems optimizing the code (assuming `rfind` doesn't blow the inline budget). As a matter of fact hotspot manages to remove virtual calls and fixes up problems if its assumptions get later invalidated, hence with enough engineering effort there's nothing that would stop a python runtime from doing the same.

Comment: A method being redefined is just a particular case of a mutation.

Comment: @Voo I agree with you. In this particular case, the string is immutable. So I don't think data will be mutated but the method indeed could...That is the real problem

Comment: @Lattyware There's an important qualitative distinction between mutating some state in a method and changing the method itself. The first case is trivial to solve for any optimizing compiler as long as the function can be inlined. The second case is much harder to solve (and needs a runtime), but only comes up in case of virtual calls and e.g. python where you can redefine methods.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can count on the interpreter evaluating the function only once, however here is an equivalent alternative to your current code which is shorter and similar in efficiency to the two line method:

```
ori.rsplit(' ', 1)[::-1]
```

Example and timing comparison:

```
In [1]: ori = 'foo bar baz'

In [2]: [ori[ori.rfind(' ') + 1:], ori[:ori.rfind(' ')]]
Out[2]: ['baz', 'foo bar']

In [3]: ori.rsplit(' ', 1)[::-1]
Out[3]: ['baz', 'foo bar']

In [4]: %timeit [ori[ori.rfind(' ') + 1:], ori[:ori.rfind(' ')]]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 732 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit ori.rsplit(' ', 1)[::-1]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 514 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit s = ori.rfind(' '); [ori[s+1:], ori[:s]]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 490 ns per loop
```

Comment: (+1) Didn't know there was an `rsplit()`.

Comment: Really appreciate that you mentioned rsplit as well as the experiments! But I feel that another reply answered my question more directly so I accepted that one.